# how to install mac os in compaq cq40 144tu?

Tags: windows-7, mac, vmware-workstation, x86

Currently I have installed Windows 7 in my laptop.
I tried some of the options in internet but i failed.
I want to install mac os on a vmware inside win 7.

Please guide me achieve this!

Comment: one, this may be a violation of licensing for Apple's operating system, and SF doesn't endorse breaking license. Two, if there was an answer to be had, it probably belongs in the Apple stack exchange or SuperUser; I don't think it'll get much traction here.

Comment: Yeah, apparently Apple doesn't like people installing it on Windows computers. Sorry. You should though, keep looking by yourself online for ways to do this, since it depends on which OS-X you want to install and what hardware you have.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this without violating the software license for Mac OS X.